# Login required views redirecting to login even after logging in

Tags: python, django

This is my login view:

```
class login(View):
    def get(self, request):
        c = {}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response("login.html", c)
    def post(self, request):
        uname = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(username=uname, password=password)

        if user is None:
            c = {}
            c.update(csrf(request))
            return render_to_response("login.html", c)
        else:
            auth_login(request, user)
            return render(request,"dashboard.html")
```

And here is another view requires login:

```
class Index(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request):
        c = {}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        return render(request,'crm_index.html')
```

The problem is, i am logging in using login form. My app is rendering dashboard.html. But when i navigate to index that requires login, i'm asked to login again. I am never able to open index using my own login page.

If i login to my app using admin site, then i can view the index.

How i can login the user in my login view?

Comment: `auth_login` is alised to `login` from `django.contrib.auth` ?

Comment: @moonstruck Yes. Thanks for pointing out, i forgot that.